# How to search Japanese characters in lucene 3.6.2

Tags: java, lucene

```
FSDirectory fsd = FSDirectory.open(indexDirectory);

IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(fsd);

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT,"data", analyzer);
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed question, and tell us the things you have tried so far.

Comment: i have tried Lucene 3.6.2 version all the language working fine except Japanese , Chinese , Korean language search is not working in this version how to implement in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [CJKAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/cjk/CJKAnalyzer.html) or a dictionary-backed Analyzer like [lucene-gosen](https://code.google.com/p/lucene-gosen/) (for Japanese)